# Reading the variables of another function

Tags: c++

Let me introduce how I got this problem... Well, I know a little bit of FORTRAN, and now I'm learning C++.
While I read the beginnings, I'm (re)creating an old program that I have written in FORTRAN.
It do the calculation part of the topography surveying of a closed polygonal.

Well, I'm reading the book "Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++", and it says that in C++, we'd prefer to let each functions do the minimum number of things. For now, I have something like this (I ignored all the other functions):

```
int main(){

//Starting the program and reading all variables
try
{
    //Program beginning
    cout << "Hello. Welcome to the 'Topography Program'\n\n\n";

    //Reading all the information needed
    reading_is_fundamental();

    //Testing the angular tolerance
    ang_tolerance_test (number_of_points); } ...there's more subroutines' calls

catch (runtime_error& e)
{
    cerr << "error:" << e.what()<<'\n';
    return 1;
}

return 0;}
```

The "reading_is_fundamental()" is the call of a subroutine. There, I read all the information needed. My problem is lying on the second subroutine, "ang_tolerance_test (number_of_points)".

In FORTRAN, I abused too much of global variables, and now, in this book, says that we must avoid global variables.

End of story, I have two questions:

1 - This logic is correct or I misunderstood the book? Should I put some calculations (or at least the reading of the input variable, as they will appear in all the subroutine) in the main function or should I use it only to call my subroutines?

2 - If this is really the way that we should do in C++ (separate each action in one function), can somebody explain me how to  grab variables that was written in the first subroutine and send to the others, like the "ang_tolerance_test" one?

Many thanks in advance!

***EDIT***

The function "reading_is_fundamental()" is where I read all the values by keyboard. I know how to read the values by a text file in FORTRAN and, in this case, it is a great advantage, as there are so many numbers to be read. But, I don't know yet how to do this in C++, so, please, ignore that I'm reading a lot of variables by keyboard, I'm studying it yet! Actually, doesn't really matter the way that I'm reading the variables, the point is that I want those doubles, int and vectors in the others soubroutines...

Well, this is "reading_is_fundamental:

```
//This subroutine reads all the variables
void reading_is_fundamental (){
cout << "What is the linear tolerance?\n";
double lin_tolerance;
cin >> lin_tolerance;

cout << "\nHow many points did you study?\n";
int number_of_points;
cin >> number_of_points;

cout << "\nWhat's the distance between each point?\n";
vector <double> distances;
for (double dist; cin >> dist;)
distances.push_back(dist);
if (distances.size() != number_of_points) error ("The number of distances must be equal to the number of points");

cout << "\nWhat's each horizontal degree angle?\n";
vector <double> horizontal_degrees;
for (double horizontal_degree; cin >> horizontal_degree;)
horizontal_degrees.push_back(horizontal_degree);
if (horizontal_degrees.size() != number_of_points) error ("The number of angles must be equal to the number of points");

cout << "\nWhat's each horizontal minute angle?\n";
vector <double> horizontal_minutes;
for (double horizontal_minute; cin >> horizontal_minute;)
horizontal_minutes.push_back(horizontal_minute);
if (horizontal_minutes.size() != number_of_pointsint)  ("The number of angles must be equal to the number of points");  

cout << "\nWhat's each horizontal second angle?\n";
vector <double> horizontal_seconds;
for (double horizontal_second; cin >> horizontal_second;)
horizontal_seconds.push_back(horizontal_second);
if (horizontal_seconds.size() != number_of_points) error ("The number of angles must be equal to the number of points");

cout << "\nWhat's the first azimuth degree?\n";
double first_az_degree;
cin >> first_az_degree;

cout << "\nWhat's the first azimuth minute?\n";
double first_az_minute;
cin >> first_az_minute;

cout << "\nWhat's the first azimuth second?\n";
double first_az_second;
cin >> first_az_second;
cin >> number_of_points;}
```

One thing that I din't know when I was writting this is if it's correct to put void in this function. My way of thinking is taht I don't want one return, but some variables filed.

The second function is the "ang_tolerance_test()". It is not ready yet, so, I will not copy here. The thing is that when I call this function in main(),  I want to put the argument of it one value sent from "reading_is_fundamental()" (that is "number_of_points).

I hope this made my questions more clearly.

Comment: Functions should take arguments and return values. That's how you pass information around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try returning value from `reading_is_fundamental` function, which you could pass it to other function like:

```
int number_of_points = reading_is_fundamental();
//Testing the angular tolerance
ang_tolerance_test (number_of_points);
```

And define function like:

```
int reading_is_fundamental() {
    ....
    return number;
}
```

Define a class like:

```
class Record
{
  private:
  double lin_tolerance;
  int number_of_points;

  public:
  int getNumberOfPoints() { return number_of_points; }
  void setNumberOfPoints(int v) { number_of_points = v; }

  double getLinTolerance() { return lin_tolerance; }
  void setLinTolerancedouble v) { lin_tolerance = v; }
};
```

And when you read the values, create an instance of Record, keep populating the values within record and at the end return that value so that you could pass it to ang_tolerance_test. Just similar to int above instead now you will get Record object from the function.

Comment: Hmm... I don't know if this helps me. The function that I want to pass the values to others is the first, "reading_is_fundamental". The problem is that this function read one double, one int and six vectors of doubles.

Comment: while value you want to pass? I dont see anything in your code except function call as first statement after cout in your main?

Comment: I was trying to evit a bunch of codes. I will edit the first question with the codes.

Comment: @criss3008 In the `reading_is_fundamental` function, create a struct, dump the "one double, one int and six vectors of doubles" into it, and then return it.

Comment: @criss3008 Create a class with three members in it and set them all with in `reading_is_fundamental` method  and return it back to the callee which is clean approach or define global instance and reuse it or you could pass it in a function and call with in reading_is_fundamental like `ang_tolerance_test(lin_tolerance, number_of_points, distances)` and define the function as `ang_tolerance_test(double lin_tolerance,int number_of_points, vector <double> distances)`

Comment: There isn't another way to do this? I don't think I get enough knowledge of classes to understand what you did. Well, I will read all variables in the main(), this will save me a lot of effort that I can't   solve yet. Thanks by now.